# Continuously gather metrics in the background of a pytest run

Tags: python, pytest

I'm creating some automatic tests for my app using `pytest`. Every test consists of some test actions and an assertion - nothing special. However some of these tests are intentionally a bit disruptive. I would like to gather some metrics from different resources of my app and from my test environment while the tests are running, and put these metrics into a log file - I'm not interested in failing the tests based on these metrics, I just want them to understand my system better.

I'm thinking about creating a script that gathers the information that I want and creating a fixture to run it in the background of my test by using `subprocess.Popen()`. I have also thought about creating a function to gather the data and run it in parallel to my test code by using `multiprocessing`. I don't know if there are other options.

I would like to know if there is a standard, simple way to do this. I want to avoid unnecessary complexity at all costs.

Thanks!